# JSON.NET Serialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm dynamically creating text boxes and receiving numeric input from the text boxes and sending the result to an ASP.NET MVC Web Api service. Because of the way the client is implemented, pre-validating the text boxes is not very convenient. Now, when the user leaves the text boxes blank, the serialization fails because JSON.NET cannot convert an empty string to an integer. Is there a way of customizing the serialization so that if the input is blank, it's serialized as zero and no serialization exception is raised?

Comment: What if you make your method (or class) accept a nullable int instead?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to send empty textboxes to the service, it will be default 0 or null depending on it's type

Comment: It was defaulting to zero but the users didn't like it so I'm having it default to an empty string. The challenge now is with serialization ...